# What's wrong with this LoginModule? And how to authenticate users with JAAS in Jboss EAP 6.1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jaas

I'm trying to implement an authentication/authorization module just for check username and password, in a Java EE application with JAAS. I'm using Jboss EAP 6.1 to deploy. But I get 403 (Access Denied) after use LoginModule in all pages for my webapp. My LoginModule is hard coded to check "user123" and "pass123", and put a "admin" role to my user.

```
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginMod implements LoginModule {

private CallbackHandler handler;
private Subject subject;
private UserPrincipal userPrincipal;
private RolePrincipal rolePrincipal;
private String login;
private List<Principal> userGroups;
private boolean succeeded = false;

@Override
public void initialize(
        Subject subject,
        CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
        Map<String, ?> sharedState,
        Map<String, ?> options)
{

    handler = callbackHandler;
    this.subject = subject;
}

@Override
public boolean login() throws LoginException
{
    Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
    callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("login");
    callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password", true);

    try {
        handler.handle(callbacks);
        String name = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
        String password = String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1])
                .getPassword());

        if (name != null &&
                name.equals("user123") &&
                password != null &&
                password.equals("pass123")) {

            System.out.println("\t\t[LoginMod] login:"+name);
            login = name;
            userGroups = new ArrayList<Principal>();
            userGroups.add(new RolePrincipal("admin"));
            succeeded = true;
            return true;
        }
        throw new LoginException("Authentication failed");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
        throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean commit() throws LoginException
{
    if (succeeded == false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(login);
        subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);

        if (userGroups != null && userGroups.size() > 0) {
            for (Principal role : userGroups) {
                rolePrincipal = new RolePrincipal(role.getName());
                subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\t\t[LoginMod] subject contains the role:"+
                subject.getPrincipals().contains(rolePrincipal));
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean abort() throws LoginException
{
    System.out.println("\t\t[LoginMod] Aborted" );
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean logout() throws LoginException
{
    subject.getPrincipals().remove(userPrincipal);
    subject.getPrincipals().remove(rolePrincipal);
    return true;
}
}
```

I create a security domain and put a reference for this module in my standalone.xml:

```
<security-domains>
 <security-domain name="acfwebRealm" cache-type="default">
   <authentication>
      <login-module code="acfweb.autenticacao.teste.LoginMod" flag="required"/>
   </authentication>
 </security-domain>
</security-domains>
```

And declare the realm in my app a jboss-web.xml file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <jboss-web>
     <context-root>acfweb</context-root>
     <security-domain>acfwebRealm</security-domain>
   </jboss-web>
```

In my web.xml I have:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>interfaces/pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Usuarios Autenticados</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/interfaces/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>acfwebRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/logar.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/logar.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I create a j_ form to use the LoginModule, and this calls my LoginModule correctly.

```
 <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Username: " />
        <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Password: " />
        <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" />
        <h:outputText value="" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <br />
</form>
```

After sending the form data my server console show me the LoginModule sysout log:

```
INFO [stdout](http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) [LoginMod] login:user123
INFO [stdout](http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) [LoginMod] subject contains the role true
```

And then I get 403 (Access Denied), for all pages after that.

Actually I don't need to authenticate my users in database, or an external LDAP, because I have another service available for this. Maybe I don't need an complete security module using JAAS, but I need control my users by roles in my EJBS, without send data representing my users in every call from Managed Beans to EJBs, captured by a Servlet filter e.g. Anyone could help me? What I'm doing wrong in this LoginModule? What is my options for described requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>  
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/acfwebRealm</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```